# Show ui control depending on the binded viewmodel instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, interface

What is the easiest way in c#/wpf to show user controls in a window depending on the viewmodel which is binded? Let's assume i have the following view models:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A : ISomeInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

public class B : ISomeInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to have some controls on the UI, which always exists (those from the interface) and some which depends on the bindene models (`A` and `B`).

What is the easiest way to decides in xaml, whether to show controls for model `A` or for model `B`?

Or is this bad practice?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you want to inherit the xaml of base UI & then add other controls based on the derived viewmodels !!! interesting :)

Comment: Indeed dataTemplate is the way as shown by @Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `DataTemplate`, making use of the `DataType` property.

```
xmlns:MyViews="clr-namespace:My.Views.Namespace.Here"    
xmlns:MyClasses="clr-namespace:My.Classes.Namespace.Here"

...

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyClasses:A}">
    <MyViews:AView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Usage**

You can use a `ContentPresenter` to bind to the property in your View Model, here is a simple example

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ISomeInterface MyThing { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if it's needed.*

Your XAML will look like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MyThing}"/>
```

The `ContentPresenter` will automatically pick up that `AView` is assigned to the data type `A` and show the view accordingly. This allows you to put **anything** that inherits `ISomeInterface` in the `MyThing` property and the `ContentPresenter` will change it's content to match the changes.

It's a good idea to define these `DataTemplate` resources in a `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: Also `ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector` is another way of handling the assignment of the templates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Defining the DataTemplates in a ResourceDictionary is totaly clear. But i don't get how to show them with the ContentPresenter. Is it possible to add this information to your nice example?

Comment: @BendEg I have edited my answer, I hope that clears things up.

Comment: Ok, but what if `ISomeInterface` is not a member of the ViewModel, but the ViewModel inherit from it?

Comment: Ok, get it. `ContentPresenter` automatically pick the `DataTemplate`. At the beginning a do not understand how to connect `ContentPresenter` and `DateTemplate`. Thank you!

Comment: The `ContentPresenter` will automatically go off and find the `DataTemplate` associated with a type. It's a magical control powered by rainbows and unicorn dust, you don't need to think about it too much. Just as long as the `DataTemplate` is somewhere that the `ContentPresenter` can *see* it, then it'll use it.